# Adobe Air: draw vector graphics

Tags: javascript, air, svg

Does Air supports SVG and if it not possible is there another way to event sensitive graphics draw via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But I found a way to draw vector graphics, using flash, over the html

```
air.Shape = window.runtime.flash.display.Shape;
this.shape = new air.Shape();
this.shape = new air.Shape();     
this.shape.graphics.lineStyle(1,0); 
this.shape.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,200); 
this.shape.graphics.endFill(); 
window.nativeWindow.stage.addChild(this.shape);
```

Answer (score -1):

Adobe Air has an embedded WebKit which partially supports SVG 1.1 As an alternative rendering engine in Adobe Air application you can use Flash, which is much based on vector graphics.

Comment: Unfortunaly you're wrong. It based on webkit but no svg will be drawn. Maybe it will come with Air2